# Run curl or somthing simliar to open url in command line using a cronjob

Tags: url, curl, cron

I am trying to open urls using cronjob and curl. I have tried to use the following code curl -I -k espn.com?this=that. It works in the commandline when I run it but does not work when I try setting up a cronjob. I have tried sudo as well but it does not work. Any assistance is greatly appreciated guys!

Thank you

Comment: can you show your code, maybe some wrong in code

Comment: Additionally, please clarify what you mean by it does not work.

Comment: 45 * * * * curl -I  espn.com?this=that: that is what I have been trying to run however it does not work when I am trying to set it up as a cronjob. nothing populates in commandline when I use it.

Comment: The goal is to be able to open multiple urls through a cronjob and then the cronjob opening the urls in commandline